# Probability in statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

Suppose we've an isolated box having $N$ classical distinguishable particles in it, the box being hypothetically divided into two parts, left and right with both parts identical.

Reif says

> ...Note that there is only one way of distributing the $N$ molecules so that all $N$ of them are in the left half of the box. It represents only one special configuration of the molecules compared to the $2^{N}$ possible configurations of these molecules. Hence we would expect that, among a very large number of frames of the film, on the average only one out of every $2^{\mathrm{N}}$ frames would show all the molecules to be in the left half. If $P_{N}$ denotes the fraction of frames showing all the $N$ molecules located in the left half of the box, i.e., if $P_{N}$ denotes the relative frequency, or probability, of finding all the $N$ molecules in the left half, then
> $$
> P_{N}=\frac{1}{2^N} .
> $$

Why should we expect that, among a **very large** number of frames of the film, on the average only one out of every $2^{\mathrm{N}}$ frames would show all the molecules to be in the left half?

I have the intuition for it but how can one show this should be the case indeed rigorously?

Why can't the average be more or less than the above value?
Also how large is "very large frames of film" here?

Answer (score 3):

We assume that all the configurations are equally probable - this is one of the principal assumptions of statistical physics. It is like throwing a die with $2^N$ sides - you expect each side appear on average once in $2^N$ throws.

**Update**
As discussed in the comments, the argument above is understandable intuitively, but hard to make rigorously. It is essentially a [frequentist argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability), assuming that we can have an infinite number of trials (or observe the system for a very long time, if we assume ergodicity). The alternative, [Bayesian probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability), openly acknowledges that the equiprobability of the events is a matter of our belief, based on our previous experience, but not necessarily justified in any rigorous sense. Eventually, both approaches boil down to *belief* and *intuition* - depending on what kind of these you are willing to accept. [Axiomatic foundations of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) do not really give a *rigorous* answer: they might help developing the mathematical apparatus, but still require postulating the probability distribution.

**Relevant quote:**
The following quote is attributed to Arnold Sommerfeld:

> Thermodynamics is a funny subject.
> The first time you go through it, you don’t understand it at all.
> The second time you go through it, you think you understand it, except for one or two points.
> The third time you go through it, you know you don’t understand it,
> but by that time you are so used to the subject, it doesn’t bother you anymore.

**Remark:**
What makes the things even more confusing is that further in studying of statistical physics one encounters the situations where the equiprobability of events does break: everything that can be associated with terms *critical phenomena*, *phase transitions*, *ergodicity breaking*, *spontaneous symmetry breaking*.

Comment: Why should I expect thate each side appear on average once in 2N throws ? I seem to have the intuition but how to make it more rigorous?

Comment: Foundations of probability theory are a tricky thing, and there is also the debate between Bayesians and frequentists (statistical physics mainly relies on frequentist interpretation of probability, as described in your question). You may look for [probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms), but intuition is the main guide here.

Comment: So to understand it rigorously one has to understand foundation of probability?

Comment: If you want mathematically rigorous understanding, you need the foundation of probability. For physically rigorous, you need to see how the arguments of stat physics agree with experimental data. It is also a good idea to note this question for later - you might have a better perspective after you learn the whole subject.

Comment: I think I'll go with your advice. How do I "see how the arguments of stat physics agree with experimental data". Isn't it by just accepting this question like an axiom and then observing that the results it produces agree with experiments?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit like this - you accept this as an axiom, and you will see how it works... I tried to add a bit more material to my answer, but it is a rather fundamental... or even philosophical question that you ask.

Comment: We will meet after "long time"...  thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If we have $N$ independent particles each of them has a 50-50% chance to be in the left compartment of the box. Hence, it is analog to throwing a coin and determining for each particle in which compartment it is put -- head corresponds to the left compartment and tails to the right. Now ask yourself, what is the probability that

1. if we have $N=1$ particle that it goes into the left compartment?
2. if we have $N=2$ particles that both are in the left compartment?
3. if we have $N=3$ particles that both are in the left compartment?

Do you see how the $1/2^N$ is the general formula for the probability?

Comment: Thank you, I understand that. My question was why should the average value be 1/2^N

Comment: If we have a dice with six faces, how often do we have to roll it **on average** to obtain a six? A probability of $1/6$ means that on average we have to throw it six times to obtain a single event.

Comment: How do we know that we've to throw it six times on average?

Comment: I believe this is a very basic question. If you don't accept that this is the case for a dice, you should read about probability theory, what probability represent, and how expectation values are defined. Start with the so called frequentist interpretation of probability, because this is what we use in physics -- except in advanced data evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ denote the probability of a specific observation type - in this case, $p=2^{-N}$. But never mind the exact value of $p$: the question is why $p$ is a limiting proportion in the large-sample case.

We assume each observation is independent of others in this probability. In $k$ observations, the number that "fit the bill" is [$\operatorname{B}(k,\,p)$-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), with mean $kp$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{kp(1-p)}$. Equivalently, the proportion has mean $\mu=p$ and standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{p(1-p)/k}$, so $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}=\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{kp}}$, which $\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.